# Principal Frame on a neighborhood

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}.$ Is it always possible to find a local principal frame near a point $p\in M?$ To be more precise, could we always find a neighborhood $U$ of $p,$ on which there exists orthonormal vector fields $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ such that
$$A(v_i,v_j)=-k_i\delta_{ij}$$
where $A$ is the second fundamental form and $k_i$'s are the principal curvatures?

I know that this could be done at a point $p,$ but I am not sure if this could be done locally, or if there exists counterexample.

Any comments or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: As long as the principal curvatures are (locally) distinct, there is no problem here. The problem comes when principal curvatures duplicate (e.g., umbilic points on a surface in $\Bbb R^3$): At such a point, there is no well-defined (hence smooth) choice of the frame.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment! That's exactly what I worry about. When there are two eigenvalues coinciding, is there any example showing that such a frame does not exist smoothly?

Comment: Just work on the surface case. Along curves you can define a limiting value continuously, but those limiting values will be different along different curves (in nontrivial cases). Just take a family of symmetric matrices varying with *two* parameters with repeated eigenvalue (say $0$) at the origin and distinct eigenvalues elsewhere. This sort of phenomenon necessitates a blow-up construction in geometry (replacing the point with the set of tangent directions at the point).

Comment: Hmm... just take a surface of revolution so $\mathbf{e}_r$ and $\mathbf{e}_\theta$ are your principal directions, but they don't extend continuously to $0$.

Comment: but at least the set on which there exist smooth principal frames is generic, right?

Comment: based on this paper https://reurl.cc/a5eVeQ

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your elaboration. Finally I found out that those good points near which there exists smooth principal frames form a dense open set. That suffices for my purpose.

Comment: @user10354138 Also thanks you! Sorry that the comment system only allows me to tag one person in a comment.